# how do i know the foregroundServiceType for a particular foreground service

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, cordova-android, android-14

As we all know, we need to explicitly mention the type of foreground Service in the manifest for upgrading to android 14 from android 13, For most of the services i have included the line

```
android:foregroundServiceType="exampleType"
```

but there is one issue that, my project is a cordova based project with many flavors, and each flavor has its own manifest file, in that manifest file i have a line

```
<service android:name="org.apache.cordova.background.ForegroundService" />
```

which is basically representing the ForegroundService file from [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/blob/master/src/android/ForegroundService.java), so i wanted to ask if a foregroundServiceType needs to be mentioned here as well and if yes then what should it be?

Answer (score 1):

If your app targets Android 14, it must specify appropriate foreground service types.

**How to Choose Service Type :**

**Foreground Service Types:**

**connectedDevice** : Used for services interacting with connected devices (e.g., Bluetooth, USB).

**dataSync** : Suitable for services synchronizing data in the background.

**health**: For services related to health monitoring and fitness tracking.

**location** : Essential for services that continuously acquire or monitor the user's location.

**media** : The primary type for playing media (audio or video) in the background.

**mediaProjection** : Applies to services that utilize the media projection API for capturing or sharing the screen.

**microphone**: Only used for services requiring the microphone while running in the foreground.

**phoneCall**: Specific to services directly involved in phone calls or VoIP communication.

**remoteMessaging**: Used for services handling remote messaging like chat or notifications.

**shortService**: Applicable for short-lived foreground services completing tasks within a few seconds.

**specialUse**: Reserved for approved system partners for specific use cases.

**systemExempted**: Predefined by the system, not intended for general usage.

For Example if your are using
android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"  in service Manifest  You need to handle service info in You respective Service class onStartCommand

Example code Handled for Both 14 and below devices

if (intent != null) {
val serviceType = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
0
} else {
ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
}

}

If you still need clarification you can visit this link which official developer documentation by google
[Please check this link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required)

Comment: Sorry, thats not quite the answer i was looking for, i am aware of the foregroundServiceTypes, but for a service which is basically taken up from a cordova plugin what should be the type and if there should be a type for this case

Comment: may i know what function does your service do  ? @Akshatkant

Comment: Hey @Kiruba, This is the service class, please check this out
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/blob/master/src/android/ForegroundService.java

Comment: This means you need to know exactly what type should be used for if their is a service with some functionalities, Excatly you need to know how to use the right foreground service attribute for all case ?

Comment: if yes in your case i will be using the data sync  because other service attributes and work  principle are not fit for your service class i think oo this is not my exact answer just a try on this , Correct if  am wrong @Akshatkant

Comment: i was also thinking about dataSync, because others dont make much sense, dataSync is also not 100% accurate for it i guess, there is a point mentioned in the official doc which says that "If a use case in your app isn't associated with any of these types, we strongly recommend that you migrate your logic to use WorkManager or user-initiated data transfer jobs.", do you think my case falls under that @Kiruba

Comment: i think work manager is good choice and it was in current trend where you can use periodical work and  onetime work request to the system , In your case my answer is using datasync because most developer are using this as i know But recent i times i haved learned work manager which was pretty easy and having more option to use i prefer both cases @Akshatkant

if this  discussion help you please upVote  or mark as correct may be helpfull for other developers also

Comment: Do you have any idea, if we put a wrong foregroundServiceType in a service, then does it give us error showing a wrong type, or it just goes on with the service, because of what i understood an error would be when there is no foregroundService type mentioned and not if a type is mentioned that may or may not be accurate like in this case dataSync. @Kiruba

Comment: and can i know on what basis did you suggest using dataSync @Kiruba

Comment: At first i have anlysed the functioanlities which you have written in your service class . i have already faced this case in own project where no type been fit so we used data sync their , it works like charm here , that's why i have suggested you this ,

Comment: Pls check and comment here if you face any errors we can check  @Akshatkant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257073/discussion-between-kiruba-and-akshat-kant).

Comment: i guess i found the perfect type which is specialUse what do you think about this, but it is specially mentioned that can use this if no other meets requirements, the only think is i need to add a reason of choosing this type because apprantely the google play will review this reason. what are your thoughts about this @Kiruba

Comment: i think  than this  foregroundservice type   you can consider work manager which is better than all @Akshatkant

Comment: Honestly i have not used this special case so far but i can try from my end and i can give my answer,better consider work manager  which means  in upcoming Android version updates Work manager will play a vital role than service so please consider this also , thanks !!